# Reading data from a BLE smartband failed with app inventor

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, at-command, app-inventor

I have a smartband (DS-D6) that communicates values through AT commands with the use of two UUIDs (0000190b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb and  0000190a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb). I confirmed these two UUIDs are working using a Serial BLE Terminal App. However, only one of the UUID (0000190b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) is working, with app inventor (using latest BLE extension). I don’t know what is going wrong. The device is connected but there is no response to AT commands when I use 0000190a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb service UUID, while everything works well using the other UUID. I double checked the UUID numbers carefully and also confirmed them using nRFconnect app. I tried to interchange characteristic UUID values, still it didn't work. I don't understand what is causing this behavior that only of the service UUIDs is working with app inventor while both of them are working with BLE serial APP. I attached here the relevant blocks from App inventor. Please note that I am using only of the service UUIDs at a time. More information about the smartband can be found in the following link
https://github.com/fanoush/ds-d6/wiki/Bracelet-commands

[image]
[image]

[image: ()]

Comment: So are you saying you can not write to one of the four GATT characteristics? Or you cant notify or read?

Comment: Using the APP inventor, I am not able to write to the GATT characteristic 00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb of the primary service 0000190a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb and read the response from the characteristic 00000002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. However, I am able to write to the GATT characteristic 00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb of the primary service 0000190b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb and read the response from the characteristic 00000004-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb.  Please note that, I have no issues with any of the characteristics while using BLE Serial App.

Comment: I am not familiar with app inventor, but what is the error? That the UUID is not found or no permissions? Or that it is not writable Or a null error?

Comment: Usually, when we write at commands to the 00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, I receive a notification on  00000004-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. Similarly, I was expecting a notification on 00000002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb when I send at commands to 00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. This expectation is realistic as I was doing with BLE Serial APP. The only issue is with the APP inventor. I also found that even with nRFConnect also not giving receiving on 00000002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. I don't know if something is wrong with primary service 0000190a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb.

Comment: You say nrf_connect is not receiving but is that a notification or a single instance of data? If it is notifications this is actually done by writing a small command to the characteristic usually 0x01 to turn notifications on.

Comment: I can turn on the notification by clocking on the down arrows. I did the same for 0000190b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb and I am able to both send and receive the data

Comment: It is notification, sorry forgot to answer clealy

Comment: Thats good, so its the characteristic "0002..." that you can not set notifications for?

Comment: Yes, that is true.